# Automatically add rows into a MS Word table in a loop as long as you read data from the excel sheet

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm a VBA newbie and having lots of errors and problems as I go on about this task. Any help will be appreciated.

Basically I have a textbox (TextBox1) in a Word doc. that I have for users to type in. It'll be a number and that text references back to a folder with Excel files with numbers as their name.

All the Excel files in that folder has the same formatting (created from the same template), but the number of rows in each file differs from one another.

My boss wants me to create a VBA code in Word to import data from Excel into the word doc, but the problem occurs with varying number of rows in each file, as users can select from any existing file in the folder.

Someone suggested creating rows in a loop as long as there is data to pull from Excel, but I just cannot get the code to work. It especially keeps failing where I'm setting the word table cell and Excel cell equal to each other (which I don't even know I'm doing right).

Here is what I have so far:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim tbl As Table
Dim row As row

Set tbl = ActiveDocument.Tables(3)
Set row = tbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(1))
    tbl.Rows(1).Range.FormattedText = tbl.Rows(2).Range.FormattedText
    '~~~> This is required as the above code inserts a blank row in between
    tbl.Rows(2).Delete

Dim objExcel As Excel.Application
Dim exWb As Excel.Workbook
On Error Resume Next
Set exWb = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("S:\Electro-Protocol\Mot_Protocols\" & TextBox1 & ".xls")

row.Cells(0) = exwb.Sheets("Tabelle1“).Cells(4,1)
'Now you just need to define the loop in which you execute the previous mentioned code. Here's some pseudo code you got to adapt in VBA for yourself:

For counter = 0 To ExcelSheetLength Step 1

       row.Cells(1) = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 0)
       row.Cells(2) = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 1)
       row.Cells(3) = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 2)
 Next counter

For counter = 0 To ExcelSheetLength Step 1
If counter = 25 Or counter = 26 Or counter = 27 Then
    'nothing
 Else
    Set row = tbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(2))

End If
 Next counter
End Sub
```

So basically, it's a mess. I'm trying to import data from a selection of Excel worksheets with the same format, but varying number of rows into a Word table that'll dynamically add rows in a loop as long as I have data to read in the Excel sheet.

The information I want from Excel starts at A4 and goes to D4, which I want in Word doc Tables(3), starting at row 1, column 1 to column 4. The Excel template repeats itself over and over until it is finished with all the data. There is 5 repeated unnecessary rows after every 8 rows. So not sure how to loop that around since I'm planning on ignoring/skipping the 5 repeating rows of unnecessary info while importing data into Word.

I know this sounds really confusing, so let me know if you have any questions.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I feel like I'm trying to just form rows and didn't cite where to import what from each Excel cell... Ugh this is so hard...

Comment: At the risk of insulting you this is a serious question, do you have any experience with debuging in the VBA IDE?  This allows you to step through each line of code and see the values in variables.  This allows you to track the results of the logic an figure out exactly what is going wrong. I can give you some pointers in chat if needed.

Comment: I would take out the line "On Error Resume Next". That should be used with great caution.  And when appropriate to use, after the code you are allowing to fail you should have a "on error goto 0".  That tells it to resume notifying you of errors.  How it is, your code might be producing some error and it will not tell you about it because of that.  It is sort of like leaving the seen of an accident.

Comment: Also putting "Option explicit" at the very top of your form code (the very first line) may help.  I assume you don't have it because you left in my example lines value1= value2= and it didn't complain that you don't have those variables defined.  But that could be because the on error resume next also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add your rows as you read excel. Inside that loop.

```
For counter = 0 To ExcelSheetLength Step 1

    row.Cells(1) = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 0)
    row.Cells(2) = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 1)
    row.Cells(3) = exWb.Sheets("Tabelle1").Cells(counter, 2)

    Set row = tbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(2))
    'set the table column values here with the row.cells 1-3

Next counter
```

I've always preferred this style loop personally

```
Dim iCount as integer
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet
lRow = 4
Do While lRow <= ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count

    value1 = ws.Range("A" & lRow).Value
    value2 = ws.Range("B" & lRow).Value

    Set row = tbl.Rows.Add(BeforeRow:=tbl.Rows(2))
    'set the table column values here with the row.cells 1-3

    'Here you deal with the extras
    iCount = iCount  + 1
    if icount = 8 then
        iCount = 0
        lrow = lrow + 5
    else
        lRow = lRow + 1
    End if

    ws.Range("A" & lRow).Activate
Loop
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow by the way. Please accept the answer that works for you.  Let me know if you need any other help.

Answer (score 0):

So for your sub-question:

> There is 5 repeated unnecessary rows after every 8 rows. So not sure how to loop that around since I'm planning on ignoring/skipping the 5 repeating rows of unnecessary info while importing data into Word.

For this, there are a couple ways to handle it. 1)ingest everything from your excel sheet, blank rows included and delete them after using VBA in MS WORD. I don't really like the idea of this approach as much as I think on it.

2) A slightly slower route would be to write an **IF** statement that looks at the data on a given line about to be ingest from EXCEL and determines if that value is BLANK/SPACE/EMPTY (whatever value is relevant for the examined piece), move on to the next line and re-start the check. IF the check comes up as having valid data, ingest and add to MS WORD table as desried.